# Oracle insert procedure inserts only 1 row instead of bulk

Tags: oracle, insert, append, procedure

I am attempting to grab a variable max date from a table, then use that variable to insert the records into another table that are greater than the variable max date.  I have created the procedure and tested it but it only inserts 1 record each time I run the procedure as a scheduled job through dbms_scheduler to run every 30 minutes.  My test case allowed for the first run to insert 6 rows, after the first job run it only inserted 1 record of the 6 records.  Then the next run inserted 1 record...etc. I am testing this to ultimately be used in concept to insert append a few thousand rows every 30 minutes as a scheduled job.  What is the most effective way to run this type of procedure quickly and bulk insert the rows.  I was considering altering the table to nologging and dropping any indexes and rebuild them after the insert. What is the best approach, thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```
create or replace procedure update_cars
AS
v_date date;
begin
execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'';
select max(inventory_date) into v_date from car_equipment;
insert /*+APPEND*/ into car_equipment(count_cars,equipment_type,location,inventory_date,count_inventory) 
select count_cars,equipment_type,location,inventory_date,count_inventory 
from car_source where inventory_date > v_date;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you altering session? What benefit do you expect from it?

Code you wrote can be "simplified" to

```
create or replace procedure update_cars
as 
begin
  insert into car_equipment (count_cars,, equipment_type, ...)
    select s.count_cars, s.equipment_type, ...
    from car_source s
    where inventory_date > (select max(e.inventory_date) from car_equipment e);
end;
```

If code inserts only one row, then check date values from both `car_equipment` and `car_source` tables. Without sample data, I'd say that everything is OK with code (at least, it looks OK to me).

If you'll be inserting a few thousand rows every 30 minutes, that shouldn't be a problem as Oracle is capable of handling that *easily*.

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot, I never thought to examine the dates.  I think this test database uses NLS_DATE_FORMAT as 'DD-MON-YY', I was altering the date to be able to ensure the data update is down to a second.  Should I also add a commit; before the end; ??

Comment: You're welcome. Date format doesn't matter. Oracle stores DATE datatype values up to seconds anyway; it is the presentation layer that shows time or not, so - you don't need such an ALTER SESSION. As of COMMIT: as the procedure will be called via scheduler, then yes - include it. Otherwise, you should leave that decision to the procedure caller.

Comment: Thanks again Littlefoot,I will run this with the commit and schedule another job to test with the date "as is" and include the max date in the where clause.  Thanks for clearing up a troublesome issue that I couldn't wrap my head around.  This forum is wonderful for bouncing ideas off experts like you! :-)

Comment: Quick question, what if the datatype is a timestamp- would that effect the outcome?

Comment: No; it behaves as DATE, but has additional precision, up to fractional seconds. Query I wrote would work just the same.